# How to prove integers are finite in Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

I have a little snippet of c that looks like this:

```
double sum(double a, double b) {
return a+b; }
```

When I run this with eva-wp, I get the error:

```
non-finite double value. assert \is_finite(\add_double(a, b));
```

But when I add :

```
requires \is_finite(\add_double(a, b));
```

then it gets status unknown.

I feel like I'm making a very simple mistake, but I don't know what it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider `file.c`:

```c
/*@ requires \is_finite(\add_double(a,b)); */
double sum(double a, double b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

and launch Eva with `frama-c -eva -main sum file.c`, we indeed have an Unknown status, and the alarm is still there. In fact, these are two separate issues.

First, when there is a `requires` clause in the main entry point, Eva tries to evaluate it against the generic initial state that it computes anyway, in which `double` values can be any finite `double` (or even infinite or NaN, depending on the value of the kernel option `-warn-special-float`). In this generic state, the `requires` does not hold, hence the `Unknown` status.

Second, Eva is not able to take advantage of the `requires` clause to reduce this initial state to an abstract state in which the property holds: this would require maintaining some kind of relation between `a` and `b`, which is not in the scope of the abstract domains currently implemented within Eva. Hence, the analysis is done with exactly the same abstract state as without the `requires`, and leads to the same alarm.

In order to validate the `requires` (and make the alarm disappear), you can use a wrapper function, that will build a more appropriate initial state and call the function under analysis, as in e.g.

```c
#include <float.h>
#include "__fc_builtin.h"
/*@ requires \is_finite(\add_double(a,b)); */
double sum(double a, double b) {
  return a+b;
}

void wrapper() {
  double a = Frama_C_double_interval(-DBL_MAX/2, DBL_MAX/2);
  double b = Frama_C_double_interval(-DBL_MAX/2, DBL_MAX/2);
  double res = sum(a,b);
}
```

`Frama_C_double_interval`, declared in `__fc_builtin.h` in `$(frama-c -print-share-path)/libc` together with similar functions for other scalar types, returns a random double between the bounds given as argument. Thus, from the point of view of Eva, the result is in the corresponding interval. By launching `frama-c -eva -main wrapper file.c`, we don't have any alarm (and the `requires` is valid). More generally, such wrappers are usually the easiest way to build an initial state for conducting an analysis with Eva.

Comment: I was sure I'd already thanked you for this very helpful answer, but it appears my comment isn't showing. So, thanks again!